# parcels do not display at some scale in SAEx

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, saex

We have a geodatabase of cadastral parcels of every district. In some of the database, the map is black in some areas, on zooming in/out those areas display whereas other areas become blank. we have tried importing the database to the newer version as well but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long use and updates, the database size increases and ArcGIS usually have the problem displaying larger dataset. The solution is to compact and repair the database from MS Access to reduce the file size which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply importing into a new database also solves the problem. This is same as compacting but also takes cares of version mismatch in database